# how to fetch all followings posts using mongodb aggregation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

i have followings Collection

```
_id:objectId('643668e0beaf5f41fdd19cf0')
userId:objectId('6436649f15da05f1398e4935')
followings:[64364fa540eb588f9a424939]
}
```

and post collection

```
userId:objectId('64364fa540eb588f9a424939')
other data fields
```

with the given code below i'm getting followings list which is working fine

```
 const followings = await this.followingService.getFollowingIds(
            data.userId,
          );
          const followingsArray = [];
          followings.forEach((obj) => {
            followingsArray.push(obj.followings);
          });
          const r = followingsArray.flat();
```

but when i try to match the ids in followingsArray with userId and fetch all posts that matches the ids in followingsArray this code gives me empty array in return

```
const re = await this.socialPostModel
            .aggregate([
              {
                $project: {
                  _id: 1,
                  userId: 1,
                  location: 1,
                  caption: 1,
                  postAudiencePreference: 1,
                  postType: 1,
                  media: 1,
                  likesCount: 1,
                  commentCount: 1,
                  createdAt: 1,
                  voucherId: 1,
                  updatedAt: 1,
                  followingsArray: r,
                },
              },
              {
                $unwind: '$followingsArray',
              },
              {
                $match: {
                  userId: '$followingsArray',
                 
                },
              },
            ])
            .skip(offset)
            .limit(limit);
          console.log('re = ', re);
```

but if i replace "$followingsArray" in match stage with userId like this

```
userId: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(
                    '64364fa540eb588f9a424939',
                  ),
```

it gives me the posts back. i can't figure it out why this is happening. can anyone help me please?